# Pulling Data from a Live Google Sheet and Emailing It

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-sheets, smtplib, gspread

I need to pull both a username and an extension from a Google sheet and then email it to the users once a week. I've written an extremely inelegant solution that I will attach below. I'm certain it can be reduced substantially with a well-written loop and some logic. I'd appreciate any nudge in the right direction. I started working on this two days ago with zero programming knowledge so please excuse any obvious blunders!

EMAIL problem:
I'd need to put in each row_number([3])+'obfuscated.com' in every subject line and then insert row_number([1]) into every body.

EDIT: For clarification, I simply manually wrote in each row variable by hand. The number of users changes weekly, but I wrote it up to forty as it will never go above that.

```
import gspread
import json
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
json_key = json.load(open('obfuscated'))
scope = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds']
credentials =        ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('obfuscated.json',
scope)
gc = gspread.authorize(credentials)

sh = gc.open_by_key('obfuscated')
worksheet = sh.get_worksheet(0)


row_1 = worksheet.row_values(2)
print(row_1[3]+'@obfuscated')
print(row_1[1])

row_2 = worksheet.row_values(3)
print(row_2[3]+'@obfuscated')
print(row_2[1])
```

I'm sorry - Here's the .csv
https://www.dropbox.com/s/i5p3m32m2huiffr/example-march.csv?dl=0

@Racialz - I'd need both the username with '@obfuscated.com' appended and personal extension as a variable I can insert into many emails.

Comment: Can you show us what your spreadsheet looks like? Obviously use some fake data but in the exact same format as your real one. Also show an example of the kind of output you would like to see from this spreadsheet

Comment: You gotta be kidding me... you seriously posted a picture of the spreadsheet.. make the spreadsheet public or upload it somewhere. Or even export it as a csv and post the plaintext here. Anything but a picture really

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go, it took forever for me to finally get a setup using your data and setting up an oauth to use with gspread but after that it's super simple.

```
currentRow = 2
while 1:
    thisRow = worksheet.row_values(currentRow)

    if (thisRow[1] == ""):
        break

    username = thisRow[3] + "@obfuscated.com"
    personalExtension = thisRow[1]

    #email sending code goes here
    print(username, personalExtension)
    currentRow += 1
```

You just get item at index `[3]` for username and item at index `[1]` for personal extension. It loops until it hits a row with no personal extension. This will work with any number of emails.

Comment: You're welcome. Just curious, how many lines was your original where you hard coded the numbers?